# Inertial scrolling in UIPageControl with UIScrollView

Tags: scroll, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled, and a corresponding `UIPageControl` to indicate the current page. This works well, but I'd like to introduce inertial scrolling to navigate multiple pages with one swipe.

One example I've seen of this is the StickTennis app for iOS. How can I do something similar?

[image: See Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd set the `pagingEnabled` property of the scroll view to `NO`, then you'd calculate the speed of the scrolling at the moment the user's finger leaves the screen using numerical derivation. From now on, you could use the `s = v0 * t + a / 2 * t ^ 2` formula to calculate the new position of the scroll view (when `a` is a constant deceleration rate and `v0` is the speed you just calculated), and then you'd repeatedly call `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` with an appropriately updated `rect` argument.

Comment: Sounds pretty simple! Thanks, I'll try this out!

Comment: @VinodVishwanath You're welcome. Yes, I think it's pretty straightforward, indeed.

Comment: I had some trouble catching the `touchesEnded` event on the `UIScrollView`, so instead I calculated the speed by finding the difference between `uiView.contentOffset.x` values in the `scrollViewDidScroll` method. 
However your answer is logical so I marked it. Thanks again!

Comment: @VinodVishwanath No problem, that's a good (if not better) solution.